# Can we add a digital signature using itextsharp while a pdf file is being created?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have checked many questions that have been asked on stackoverflow and even read articles and books on itextsharp digital signature but could never find any solution. I want to add a digital signature at the end of my pdf file while I am writing the file. Is it possible to do that as PdfStamper.CreateSignature uses a pdfreader parameter. Could someone please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no high-level iText API to allow single pass document creation and signing.

You can of course try and port the `PdfStamper` oriented signing code to `PdfWriter` oriented signing code. But this does not really help that much.

For example this won't allow you to simply stream the PDF in creation to a response stream as the signature to embed somewhere in the middle of the PDF cannot be created before the whole PDF except the signature is created.

If you want to *sign while creating the PDF* because that's when you best know where to put the signature, you can instead create an *empty signature field* which can be signed in a later step.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry for replying late. A follow up question, is it possible to digitally sign word documents?

Comment: Yes. But they are different, in particular a word document signature does not become a pdf signature upon export to pdf.

Comment: @RubenCharles that being said, did my answer clear the questions you had on the original topic,  the pdf signatures.

Comment: Yes it did clear the question I had on the original topic. Thank you!